# Using transactions with pg_update() PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I a using pg_update() to update my data dynamically.

I have more than one tables to update. I want to rollback if any query fails.

We can use transactions with static queries but Is there any way to use transactions with pg_update() because I have to use dynamic queries using pg_update().

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution to my problem

```
  pg_query("BEGIN") or die("Could not start transaction\n");
        $dataToUpdate = array('name' => $name);;
        $condition = array('id' => $id);
        $res1 = pg_update($this->dbConnection, 'table_name1', $dataToUpdate, $condition);
        $res2 = pg_update($this->dbConnection, 'table_name2', $dataToUpdate, $condition);
       if ($res1 && $res2) {
        pg_query("COMMIT") or die("Transaction commit failed\n");
    } else {
        pg_query("ROLLBACK") or die("Transaction rollback failed\n");;
    }
```